# What happened to Irony Games' tools?

Tags: map-making, tools

About five years ago, there used to be a site called Irony Games that hosted a variety of useful map generator tools (Non-functional list of tools shown [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20050205083401/www.irony.com/webtools.html)).  Have these tools ever been re-hosted elsewhere or are they lost forever?  A quick Google search found a lot of dead ends.

Here's a sample of what two villages and an inn (for example's sake) were like--click for larger images. (With thanks to user [DustScribe](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/44210/dustscribe) for scanning their old printouts!)

[image: village1 p.1]
[image: village1 p.2]
[image: village2 p.1]
[image: village2 p.2]
[image: inn]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Severe financial problems. I couldn't afford the hosting and sold the domain name. All these years later I'm still working on recovery. Even so, I'm proud that I had a useful website before Microsoft was even on the net! ... I did keep the hard drives for a long time but they are gone now. Sad. And yes, 'irony' did come from the location of my packet radio repeater site located in IroNY located in Irondequoit, New York.

I'm so grateful to read how much it was used and I am sorry for the loss.

Ed no-longer-at irony.com

Comment: Technically this is the full (and presumably correct) answer to the OP's question, as phrased: "Whatever happened to . . ."

Comment: I never expected you to pop up on the site in person.  Your website and tools were the foundation of my early RPG gaming days in the mid to late 90s.  Town maps, mazes, dungeons, and description generators.  Very rock-solid foundation tools for any newbie DM.  Thank you for the services you provided.

Comment: @Ed.T - I too used your tools back in the day and I thank you!  Let me know if you ever find backups of your code, and I'd be happy to host them on my website.

Comment: Ed, take a look at this, it might interest you. Let me know when you're done so I can remove this otherwise useless comment. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/34453/4173

Answer (score 15):

The irony games generator is long gone, as far as I can tell.

When it dissapeared, I started coding my own generators.
I guess they'd be better if I dedicated a bit more time to them, but at least they help me with my games (they might be useful for you too).

And if you don't like them, check my "about" page. I try to link to other people's generators.

http://rpg20.com/

Comment: Roflo, welcome to RPG.SE. Make sure you read our [FAQ]. Answers are not "posts" and therefore do not require a signature line.

Comment: *This* is how to post about your own site—useful, topical, and a touch of the personal experience with the asker's problem. Welcome to RPG.SE!

Answer (score 11):

I've looked more than once for replacements for their tools over the last few years.  I've found a couple of decent replacements for certain items at sites such as [Inkwell Ideas](http://inkwellideas.com/), which has decent random generators for inns, cities, magic shops, villages and small dungeon maps.  There are other good resources here and there as well to replace the tools that Irony offered.

As to what happened to the original Irony Games site, it just up and disappeared one day.  I've never found re-hosted copies of the original tools they had there.  I've seen various theories about what happened from legal problems to the owner died, but I've never found an "official" reason.

Answer (score 6):

Most are probably lost to the public; the author may or may not have backups of the backend scripts that actually do the heavy lifting.

Most could be readily recreated from scratch by a competent programmer, as well. Several have been, by [Inkwell ideas](http://inkwellideas.com).